# Issue with showing OpenLayers map inside Materialize layout

Tags: html, css, openlayers, materialize, openlayers-3

I'm having problem with showing full map inside layout created using materialized framework. 
I'm having issues with footer area where I can't figure out how to remove white space in footer area. It looks something like this on wider screen.

[image]

On smaller screen it looks like this.

[image]

I tried with this:

```
.map {
 height: 100%;
 width:100%;
}
```

but without any luck.

Also, I'm wondering how to prioritize navbar and put it above map.

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Svinjica/b76ns3ua/) with described problem. zhank you

Comment: set `position: absolute` and use calcuated height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late answer but here it goes:

I simply added `flex 1 0 auto` in for header, main and footer section

```
header, main, footer {
    padding-left: 300px;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

and for body section I added `display: flex; attribute`

Like this:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Now map is scaling properly inside defined layout.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
.map {
 position:absolute;
 margin-top:100px;
 height: calc(100vh-100px);
 width:100vw;
 }
```

Try this css, I guess it will make your work easy.